# How to rebuild the packed-refs file

Tags: git, github

**Context**

I am writing a script to mirror and periodically refresh some repositories from GitHub. GitHub repos have reference to Pull request branches that have no meaning outside, so I am filtering them out as suggested in [Howto: Mirror a GitHub Repo Without Pull Refs](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-mirror-a-github-repository-without-pull-refs.html). So far the steps are

```
git clone --mirror SourceGitHubRepoUrl
git remote add --mirror=push alice MyMirrorUrl
git config --local --replace-all remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*" 
git config --local --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"
```

at this point the local mirror has the correct fetch rules and

```
git remote update origin
```

works nicely, but

```
git push --mirror alice
```

gives errors like `! [remote rejected] refs/pull/22/head -> refs/pull/22/head` because the `packed-refs` still lists the `refs/pull/*` branches.

**Question**

How can I fix the content of `packed-refs`? Can I simply remove all lines matching "refs/pull"?

This latter seems to work, but one is never sure that there are no lurking gremlins.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation, I was able to incrementally update the remote `origin` to the mirrored remote `backup` through a bare repo by using `git-update-ref` and `git-pack-refs`:

```
git fetch --all --prune
BRANCHES="$(git branch --remotes | grep origin/ )"
for BRANCH in $BRANCHES; do
    echo "--> setting local branch ${BRANCH#origin/} to remote branch ${BRANCH}"
    git update-ref "refs/heads/${BRANCH#origin/}" $(git rev-parse $BRANCH)
    git pack-refs --all
done
echo "--> pushing to backup"
git push --mirror backup
```

Answer (score 1):

> so I am filtering them out

Speaking of filtering, Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), "[`git pack-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cbc882ea388143bd6bbed139f97f67589777be60/Documentation/git-pack-refs.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs))</sup> learns `--include` and `--exclude` to tweak the ref hierarchy to be packed using pattern matching.

See [commit 4fe42f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fe42f326e10a547dc65dfe9e5ceaeeee02b98db), [commit 826ae79](https://github.com/git/git/commit/826ae79fca263bc2b70c54fddacb1603c5ebb9c6), [commit 283174b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/283174b214c4c5416772dcacbc6389dd192969a0) (12 May 2023) by [John Cai (`john-cai`)](https://github.com/john-cai).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cbc882e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbc882ea388143bd6bbed139f97f67589777be60), 13 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`pack-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/826ae79fca263bc2b70c54fddacb1603c5ebb9c6): teach `--exclude` option to exclude refs from being packed
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Cai</sup>

> At GitLab, we have a system that creates ephemeral internal refs that don't live long before getting deleted.
> Having an option to exclude certain refs from a packed-refs file allows these internal references to be deleted much more efficiently.
>
> Add an `--exclude` option to the pack-refs builtin, and use the ref exclusions API to exclude certain refs from being packed into the final packed-refs file

`git pack-refs` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/826ae79fca263bc2b70c54fddacb1603c5ebb9c6/Documentation/git-pack-refs.txt#L11):

> 'git pack-refs' [--all] [--no-prune] [--exclude ]

`git pack-refs` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/826ae79fca263bc2b70c54fddacb1603c5ebb9c6/Documentation/git-pack-refs.txt#L63-L72):

> ### `--exclude <pattern>`
>
> Do not pack refs matching the given `glob(7)` pattern. Repetitions of this option
> accumulate exclusion patterns. Use `--no-exclude` to clear and reset the list of
> patterns. If a ref is already packed, including it with `--exclude` will not
> unpack it.
>
> When used with `--all`, pack only loose refs which do not match any of
> the provided `--exclude` patterns.

And:

> ### [`pack-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fe42f326e10a547dc65dfe9e5ceaeeee02b98db): teach pack-refs --include option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Cai</sup>

> Allow users to be more selective over which refs to pack by adding an `--include` option to git-pack-refs.
>
> The existing options allow some measure of selectivity.
> By default [`git-pack-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fe42f326e10a547dc65dfe9e5ceaeeee02b98db/Documentation/git-pack-refs.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs))</sup> packs all tags.
> `--all` can be used to include all refs, and the previous commit added the ability to exclude certain refs with --exclude.
>
> While these knobs give the user some selection over which refs to pack, it could be useful to give more control.
> For instance, a repository may have a set of branches that are rarely updated and would benefit from being packed.
> `--include` would allow the user to easily include a set of branches to be packed while leaving everything else unpacked.

`git pack-refs` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fe42f326e10a547dc65dfe9e5ceaeeee02b98db/Documentation/git-pack-refs.txt#L11):

> 'git pack-refs' [--all] [--no-prune] [--include ] [--exclude ]

`git pack-refs` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fe42f326e10a547dc65dfe9e5ceaeeee02b98db/Documentation/git-pack-refs.txt#L63-L71):

> ### `--include <pattern>`
>
> Pack refs based on a `glob(7)` pattern. Repetitions of this option
> accumulate inclusion patterns. If a ref is both included in `--include` and
> `--exclude`, `--exclude` takes precedence. Using `--include` will preclude all
> tags from being included by default. Symbolic refs and broken refs will never
> be packed. When used with `--all`, it will be a noop. Use `--no-include` to clear and reset the list of patterns.

`git pack-refs` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fe42f326e10a547dc65dfe9e5ceaeeee02b98db/Documentation/git-pack-refs.txt#L82-L84):

> When used with `--include`, refs provided to `--include`, minus refs that are
> provided to `--exclude` will be packed.

With that, you can control what you want in your pack-refs.